# mod_rewrite to new domain except specific URL

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Folks, I must be looking in the wrong place as this seems a common problem but I couldn't find anything.

I'm trying to rewrite all URL from domain1.com to domain2.com EXCEPT domain1.com/admin - for that, I want everything to stay as is (meaning stay on domain1.com/admin/xxxxxx). I thought it was as simple as:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain1\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(admin) [NC]  
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.domain2.com [R=301,L]
```

But domain1.com/admin redirects me to domain2.com/admin - what am I doing wrong?

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+admin[/?\s] [NC]  
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain2.com [R=301,L]
```

Using `THE_REQUEST` here as your other rule might be changing `REQUEST_URI` to `index.php` or some other front controller.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^/admin [NC]   and even RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^admin [NC]   (just to be safe) and I'm still redirected to domain2.com (although not to domain2.com/admin anymore).

Comment: No you cannot use `^` like that since `THE_REQUEST` has value like this: `GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1`. You can use my updated rule for *just to be safe* part